# Getting error executing package SSIS through a job of RUNDECK

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs, rundeck

I am getting the error below when I am executing a batch command on Rundeck.

```
Source: FEXT_UC SSIS.Pipeline
12:23:27               Description: The Data Flow task failed to create a buffer to call PrimeOutput for output "Flat File Source" (39) on component "Flat File Source Output" (43). This error usually occurs due to an out-of-memory condition.
```

The data flow task is simply a csv file (~500 rows) -> derived column -> table.

Otherwise, if I run the batch command directly on cmd, it runs perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to modify the amount of memory on Rundeck to coexists with SSIS and SQL Server, check that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084796/10426011

And here how to tuning Rundeck:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/tuning-rundeck.html#java-heap-size

Comment: and if I do not have permissions to modify the amount of memory on Rundeck?